# EditText and go to next

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some EditTexts in my application and I am using:`android:nextFocusDown="@+id/last_name_edit_text"` to go to next editText push "Next" button. I have a problem with last EditText. I want to add when this is last EditText I want to change button next on finish button. How I can do that in xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in the last editText

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use imeOptions="actionDone"

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Followings may help you

- http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions

Answer (score 1):

Use  `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` on last edittext

**For Next -** `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

**For Done** - `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`